# How to print nested JSON data using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, nested

I just started programming. I'm trying to print some nested JSON data using a Python script.

Here's an example of the JSON:

```
{
"objects": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "spec_version": "2.1",
            "type": "green",
            "extensions": {
                "extension-definition--ea279b3e-5c71-4632-ac08-831c66a786ba": {
                    "extension_type": "purple",
                    "id": "2",
                    "type": "yellow",
                    "created_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "updated_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "stix_ids": [
                        "3"
                    ],
                }
            }
       }
   ]
}
```

If I have to print something like the "extension_type" in "extensions", how can I do that?
My Python script:

```
import json, requests 

url = "myUrl"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Auth',
  'Cookie': 'biscuit'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
my_json = json.loads(response.text)

for data in my_json['objects'][0]['extensions']:
    print(data)
```

The output is:
`extension-definition--ea279b3e-5c71-4632-ac08-831c66a786ba`
I can only go so far, I don't know how to access the "extension_type" and print it.

Comment: The *objects* key has a list for its value. That implies that there could be more than one element in that list - otherwise why would it be a list?. How do you propose to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {
"objects": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "spec_version": "2.1",
            "type": "green",
            "extensions": {
                "extension-definition--ea279b3e-5c71-4632-ac08-831c66a786ba": {
                    "extension_type": "purple",
                    "id": "2",
                    "type": "yellow",
                    "created_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "updated_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "stix_ids": [
                        "3"
                    ],
                }
            }
       }
   ]
}
```

You can access the `extension_type` in the data using the below piece of code:

```
data["objects"][0]["extensions"]["extension-definition--ea279b3e-5c71-4632-ac08-831c66a786ba"]["extension_type"]
```

Comment: hello, it works! thank you :) do you know the reason why it prints the data vertically? something like this: `p
u
r
p
l
e`

Comment: Because you are looping through a string. So your loop works like this: for data in "purple". You can get hold of this value without a loop.

Comment: oh ok, thank you, have a great day ^^

Answer (score 1):

I presume you know the keys as far as `extensions`, but the next key is dynamic and unknown to you. In that case, you can follow this procedure to get the `extension_type` value:

Since `my_json['objects'][0]['extensions']` is a dict, you can find the first (and in this case only) value in the dict using:

```
ext = next(iter(my_json['objects'][0]['extensions'].values()))
```

and then simply get the extension:

```
ext_type = ext['extension_type']
```

Output:

```
'purple'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (that works for the data structure in this question) is to carry out a recursive search just looking for the key of interest - wherever it might be.

For example:

```
def search(d, key):
    def _search(e):
        nonlocal key
        if isinstance(e, dict):
            if key in e:
                return e[key]
            for v in e.values():
                if (r := _search(v)) is not None:
                    return r
        elif isinstance(e, (list, tuple, set)):
            for v in e:
                if (r := _search(v)) is not None:
                    return r
    return _search(d)


data = {
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "spec_version": "2.1",
            "type": "green",
            "extensions": {
                "extension-definition--ea279b3e-5c71-4632-ac08-831c66a786ba": {
                    "extension_type": 'purple',
                    "id": "2",
                    "type": "yellow",
                    "created_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "updated_at": "2023-09-26",
                    "stix_ids": ["3"],
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}

print(search(data, 'extension_type'))
```

**Output:**

```
purple
```